# HomeSync / Mobile - Settings & keychain missing

Tags: network, osx-server, keychain, network-user, open-directory

I've recently rolled out an Open Directory domain in our office. The domain has been set up so user profiles are synced with the server via HomeSync, so we could use FileVault2 to encrypt the machines.

I recently got a new workstation and connected it to our domain. Upon logging in using my network account, I found that none of my settings or keychain were there. Thinking the settings sync might be a feature of HomeSync, I imported our workgroup profile which has HomeSync enabled on it. When logging back into the machine, HomeSync did it's thing and copied my user profile to the local machine but it wasn't until I logged in that I realised that my settings and my keychain STILL hadn't copied over.

Is there something I need to do to ensure that settings centralised for each user?

Server and clients are running 10.8

Comment: Are you configuring all of this with Profile Manager?

Comment: Can you verify the user keychain was copied to the server in the first place?  AFAIK, Keychain stores locally, but I'm not familiar with HomeSync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the ~/Library folder being in the configuration, it still wasn't being backed up. I deleted the profile, recreated it and everything appears to be working. I'm moving away from HomeSync anyway, as it doesn't listen to exclusions properly and seems to make it's own mind up a lot of the time.